# Unable to compile prismjs with angular using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, prismjs

I have created a project using **angular-cli**. I want to use **angular-prism** library in my project.

So I installed

```
yarn add angular-prism
```

and then in my **app.module.ts**

```
import { PrismComponent } from "angular-prism/angular-prism";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, PrismComponent
  ],
  // other code
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but this is showing errors

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-prism/angular-prism.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\angular-prism\angular-prism.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in
the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:719:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

So I added

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/prismjs/prism.js"]
```

in **angular.json**.

And now this is showing

```
 91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\node_modules\prismjs\prism.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:124:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:39:54)
    at Promise (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:92:49)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at scripts.map.fullPath (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:91:24)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at hook (D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\QWC\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:90:43)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `"scripts": ["node_modules/prismjs"]` may be?

Comment: @Simonare did not get you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, `angular-prism`'s build output is not in the proper manner to be consumed directly to your projects. So to make it part of the compilation, I need to make an entry in the **tsconfig.json** file under `include` like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    },
    "include": [
        "node_modules/angular-prism"
    ]
}
```

And now this is working!!!